# How to send Content-Type: text/calendar part in email through mandrill?

Tags: php, icalendar, mandrill

I saw in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178760/mandril-how-to-attach-ics-invitation-file-to-template) that mandrill doesn't support content type "text/calender".

I couldn't make the RSVP buttons to show up on outlook without this. Mandrill is simply just skipping the content type "text/calendar". is there any work around for this?

text/calendar is there in the body being sent but not visible in the email source. I'm working with PHPMailer

Comment: So...the other question already gives you the answer you need then, surely? It's not clear what else you're expecting.

Comment: @ADyson The statement from mandrill crew in that answer was 9 years ago. I wanted to know if they added the support for it or if someone found any workaround.

Comment: Well if you've tried and it's still not working correctly, that would suggest that they haven't. It's hard to see what the workaround would be, other than using a different email provider.